# C++ method only differs by 'constness' of return type (and const)

Tags: c++, constants, overloading

just stumbled over something I have not seen before. Consider you've had the following class:

```
class foo
{
    const bar* get() const;
    bar* get();
}
```

**How can a client of foo decide which get() method is used?**

Comment: It selects based on whether the access to a `foo` instance is `const` or not. The return types make no difference in overload resolution.

Comment: Yes, it based on the instance of object is const or not. If a const instance, const bar* get() const will be called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just as with any other overload on `const`ness, it depends on the access path to the object on which the function is invoked (in other words, on the type of the implicit `this` parameter).

Example:

```
void bar(foo nc1, foo &nc2, foo *nc3, const foo &c1, const foo *c2) {
  // These call the non-const version:
  nc1.get();
  nc2.get();
  nc3->get();

  // These call the const version:
  c1.get();
  c2->get();
}
```