# Array operator [] overloading const and non-const versions

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

I got an assignment to implement a template array class.
One of the requirement is to overload the [] operator.
I made this two const and non-const version which seems to be working fine.

```
const T& operator[](const unsigned int index)const
```

and

```
T& operator[](const unsigned int index)
```

My question is how will the compiler know which one to run
when i will do something like:

```
int i=arr[1]
```

On a non-const array?

Comment: It'll call the `const` version on a `const` object, otherwise the non-`const` version.

Comment: I didn't quite understood what you meant can you please elaborate?

Comment: If `arr` is const, the const version will be called.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ method only differs by 'constness' of return type (and const)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911776/c-method-only-differs-by-constness-of-return-type-and-const)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The non-const function will always be called on a non-const array, and the const function on a const array.

When you have two methods with the same name, the compiler selects the best-fitting one based on the type of the arguments, and the type of the implicit object parameter (arr).

I just answered a similar question the other day, you may find it helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16922652/2387403

Comment: Thank you that was realy helpfull.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your declaration of the object. If you have

```
const T arr[];
...
int i=arr[1];
```

Then the const version will be called, but if you have

```
T arr[];
...
int i=arr[1];
```

Then the non-const version will be called. So in the example you gave, since it was a non-const array, the non-const version will be called.

Comment: Do you mean that the compiler will simply prefer to call the non-const version over the const one?
If so can you please explain why?

Comment: @petric Yes, it will. As for why, imagine what would happen if every time you called a function it would default to the const version. It would be impossible to do anything, and moreover there would be no point in having a non-const version of the function because it would never be called.